# how can I find div class with one letter that changes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, find

I would like to scrape a website, at the moment, I can scrape the website from page 1 to 5. 
The only thing that bugs me, is that on page 3, the website changes the div class from the information I want to scrape.

from : "xl-price rangePrice"

to : "l-price rangePrice"

to : "m-price rangePrice"

```py
find("div", {"class": "xl-price rangePrice"})
```

How can I change this code so that the query scrape "xl-price rangePrice" and "l-price rangePrice" and "m-price rangePrice"?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

My overall code is this one:

```py
#Fonctionne jusqu à la page 5  mais j'ai pas la page 5 

import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
a = ua.random
user_agent = ua.random
print(user_agent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/raduulea/Documents/chromedriver', options=options)

driver.get('https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/immeuble-de-rapport/a-vendre/liege/4000')

import time

time.sleep(10)

Title = []
address = []
price = []
surface = []
desc = []
page = 2
while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    if int(page)<=2:
        results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "result-xl"})
        for result in results:
            Title.append(result.find("div", {"class": "title-bar-left"}).get_text().strip())
            address.append(result.find("span", {"result-adress"}).get_text().strip())
            price.append(result.find("div", {"class": "xl-price rangePrice"}).get_text().strip())
            surface.append(result.find("div", {"class": "xl-surface-ch"}).get_text().strip())
            desc.append(result.find("div", {"class": "xl-desc"}).get_text().strip())
        if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.next")) > 0:
            url = "https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/immeuble-de-rapport/a-vendre/liege/4000/?page={}".format(page)
            driver.get(url)
            page += 1
    elif 3 <= int(page) < 5:
        results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "result-l"})
        for result in results:
            Title.append(result.find("div", {"class": "title-bar-left"}).get_text().strip())
            address.append(result.find("span", {"result-adress"}).get_text().strip())
            price.append(result.find("div", {"class": "l-price rangePrice"}).get_text().strip())
            surface.append(result.find("div", {"class": "l-surface-ch"}).get_text().strip())
            desc.append(result.find("div", {"class": "l-desc"}).get_text().strip())
        if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.next")) > 0:
            url = "https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/immeuble-de-rapport/a-vendre/liege/4000/?page={}".format(page)
            driver.get(url)
            page += 1
    elif 5 <= int(page) <= 6:
        results = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "result-m"})
        for result in results:
            Title.append(result.find("div", {"class": "title-bar-left"}).get_text().strip())
            address.append(result.find("span", {"result-adress"}).get_text().strip())
            price.append(result.find("div", {"class": "m-price rangePrice"}).get_text().strip())
            surface.append(result.find("div", {"class": "m-surface-ch"}).get_text().strip())
            desc.append(result.find("div", {"class": "m-desc"}).get_text().strip())
        if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.next")) > 0:
            url = "https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/immeuble-de-rapport/a-vendre/liege/4000/?page={}".format(page)
            driver.get(url)
            page += 1
        else:
            break
    elif int(page) > 6:
        break


df = pd.DataFrame({"Title": Title, "Address": address, "Price:": price, "Surface": surface, "Description": desc})
df.to_csv("immo_scrap.csv")
```

If somebody needs it: 
I found another solutions, partly from the answers here, and also checking others forums:

Here is my code, much simpler now:

```py
#Fonctionne jusqu à la page 5  mais j'ai pas la page 5 

import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,600")
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
a = ua.random
user_agent = ua.random
print(user_agent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/raduulea/Documents/chromedriver', options=options)

driver.get('https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/immeuble-de-rapport/a-vendre/liege/4000')

import time

time.sleep(10)

Title = []
address = []
price = []
surface = []
desc = []
page = 2
while True:
    time.sleep(10)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    if int(page)<=6:
        results = soup.find_all(True, {"class": ["result-xl", "result-l","result-m"]})
        for result in results:
            Title.append(result.find("div", {"class":"title-bar-left"}).get_text().strip())
            address.append(result.find("span", {"result-adress"}).get_text().strip())
            price.append(result.find("div", {"class": ["xl-price rangePrice", "l-price rangePrice", "m-price rangePrice"]}).get_text().strip())
            surface.append(result.find("div", {"class": ["xl-surface-ch", "l-surface-ch", "m-surface-ch"]}).get_text().strip())
            desc.append(result.find("div", {"class": ["xl-desc", "l-desc", "m-desc"]}).get_text().strip())
        if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a.next")) > 0:
            url = "https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/immeuble-de-rapport/a-vendre/liege/4000/?page={}".format(page)
            driver.get(url)
            page += 1
    elif int(page) > 6:
        break


df = pd.DataFrame({"Title": Title, "Address": address, "Price:": price, "Surface": surface, "Description": desc})
df.to_csv("immoweb_no_secret.csv")
```

Comment: Is this class `rangePrice` unique or available in other containers as well?

Comment: It is unique, every time related to the price. 

<div class="l-price rangePrice" xpath="1"> 310.000 € </div> or <div class="xl-price rangePrice" xpath="1">
        399.000 €  
       </div>

Comment: If that is unique, why don't you try this `find("div", {"class": "rangePrice"})` to get your job done or `select_one("div[class*='-price']")`.

Comment: Thanks I think it's working for rangePrice, because it's indeed unique. But I have the same problem with <div id="8031924" class="result-xl" </div> where I would like to find 'result-l' and 'result-m'. 
But this time 'result' is not unique at all, and is all over the html in other containers...

Comment: Try `soup.select_one("[class^='result-']")`.

Comment: It's really hard to offer any hypothetical solution without going through the html layouts.

Comment: I just tries and it just gives me one result: >>> print(results)
<span class="result-title-bolder">Plus de 500 annonces trouvées</span>

Comment: Can you not share the link to that site?

Comment: Sure ! https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/immeuble-de-rapport/a-vendre/liege/4000

Answer (score 0):

You can use css ends-with selector ($=):

> div[class$="-price rangePrice"]

Comment: I can't get it working like this... driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(div[class$="-price rangePrice"])

Comment: single quotes around the selector

Answer (score 0):

Either of the following selectors should do the trick. Make sure you passed that recaptcha barrier before giving a try:

This one:

```
for item in soup.select("[data-type='resultgallery-resultitem'] .rangePrice"):
    print(item.text)
```

Or this:

```
for item in soup.select("[class^='result-'] .rangePrice"):
    print(item.text)
```

This is one of the ways:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.immoweb.be/fr/recherche/immeuble-de-rapport/a-vendre/liege/4000?page=3"

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    driver.delete_all_cookies()
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("[class^='result-'] .rangePrice"):
        print(item.text.strip())
```

Comment: I'll try this solution, in my code I use a fake_userAgent to bypass the captcha

Comment: Your solution is working thanks ! 
I just couldn't integrate it in my overall code, but when I run it alone, it gives what you said !

Comment: thanks for your help SIM !! 
It partly helped me change my code, but now it's working :)